# Changing PHP variable without refreshing the page

Tags: php, ajax

Is there anyway to assign/change a PHP variable after the page has loaded? For example, let's say I have the variable `$username`. `$username` is not set yet, but it will be set once the user has submitted a form with an input field that will set `$username`. So essentially, `$username` will become `$username = $_POST["username"];` Let's say the user decides to change the username again. (Note: the page never refreshes upon user submission, it is the same page.) $username gets assigned to $_POST["username"] again. With this current methodology, it is not working for me. I have constructed the following:

```
$prevUsername;
$newUsername;

if ((isset($_POST["username"]))
{
    $newUsername = $_POST["username"];

if ($username == "")
{
   $db->query("INSERT INTO Users (`username`) VALUES ('$newUsername')");
   $prevUsername = $newUsername;
}

else
{
   $db->query("UPDATE Users SET username = '$newUsername' WHERE username = '$prevUsername'");
   $prevUsername = $newUsername;
}
}
```

When the user submits a username, it works properly. It only stops working properly when the user wants to update their username. Updating their username does not return any errors, but it does not update based on their previous username. Instead of updating, it stays the same as if the UPDATE SQL statement never initiated. Is there a way to fix this problem?

With Session variables:

```
session_start();
ob_start();

$_SESSION["username"];
if (isset($_POST["username"]))
{
   if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
   {
       $db->query("UPDATE Users SET username = '{$_POST['username']}' WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
   }

   else
   {
      $db->query("INSERT INTO Users (`username`) VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}')");
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
   }
}
```

Comment: where the value is assigned to $prevUsername in the UPDATE query?

Comment: Those requests are processed in completely different script executions. You cannot simply expect that the values are exchanged between different runs. You have to use a session for that. See the documentation about that for details.

Comment: @arkascha Even when using session variables, I get the same outcome. I've tried using both session and regular variables, but both seem to not be working correctly as expected

Comment: Using session alone is a blank thing. You have to store certain values in there. You'd have to post your session base code for us to help with that. But make sure you first understand what the issue is with your current code. I have the impression you still struggle with how requests are processed...

Comment: @MatteoEnna Sorry, I'm simplifying my code so you can understand my problem better, that was a typo. I corrected it

Comment: @user2896120 Maybe I misunderstood. Please clarify. Does your current code already use working Ajax (meaning can you confirm that when user updates the form, your PHP username variables are also updated automatically)

Comment: That certainly is not code that uses a session. Please read an introduction to sessons in PHP. You need to actually initiate a session...

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yes, the Ajax works correctly. When the user clicks the submit button for the first time, the username is inserted into the database. Afterwards, if the user wishes to change their username to something else, the UPDATE SQL statement doesn't work correctly and does not update the entry where the old username is in.

Comment: @arkascha Yes I know, I'm just simplifying my code for this question so you can better understand what exactly I want. I'm initializing session_start() at the beginning of my code, i'll update the question so it can display it though

Comment: OK, then you have to start debugging: First add a logging statement to the update query: dump the specific query string into a log file and check what the two variables actually hold. Also check your http servers error log file, it will tell you if the query fails or is invalid or simply does not match any entry.

Comment: Apart from that: the code you posted is wide open to sql injection attacks. That might also be due to you simplifying the code, though...

Comment: @arkascha Any fatal failures or invalid sql errors are logged in an error log file on my hosting account, but how do _I add a logging statement to the update query and dump the specific query string into a log file and check what the two variables actually hold_ Also, I have a function that takes care of sql injection, not included in my question

Comment: If you construct the actual sql query the way above, as final string, then no function in the world can fix or secure that later on. Don't have a false sense of security. Read about "prepared statements" and "parameter binding", that is important.

Comment: About "dumping"... There is the `syslog()` call for example. Or you write your own logging function or class handling a specific log file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php However if you already look into your error log file and, as I understand, see no error for the update statement, then most likely you have an empty username in the session. So the query simply does not match any rows in the table

Comment: @arkascha Before I make use of the `$_POST["username"]`, I have a function that strips slashes, trims, etc. doing so like this `filter_data($_POST["username"])`

Comment: Using prepared statements and parameter binding is the preferred way to handle security. But I only want to mention the important thing. It certainly is your decision.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, there are no errors with the SQL and when I make the UPDATE WHERE clause to something I know was the previous username, it works. For example, let's say I know I will create a username called "Bob" at first. So in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement, I'll write where username = 'bob' and it will work, so it's because of the session variable failing to change values properly

Answer (score 0):

PHP is `stateless`, this means nothing is stored in the servers memory after the request is done. In other words, PHP is not capeable of keeping track of the var `$prevUsername`, because it get lost between request. What you should do is store the variables in something that is more persistent, e.g. sessions :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['prevUsername'])) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Users (`username`) VALUES (?)');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username'])
            $stmt->execute();

            $_SESSION['prevUsername'] = $_POST['username'];
        }else{
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE Users SET username = ? WHERE username = ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username'])
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['prevUsername'])

            $_SESSION['prevUsername'] = $_POST['username'];
        }
}
```

---

And if you want to use it with ajax:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="txt_username" />
            <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" />
        </form>
        <hr />
        <div id="username"></div>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <hr />
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#btn_submit').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    request();
                });
                request();
            });
            function request() {
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'http://www.darkbee.be/stack/username/process.php',
                  data: {'username':$('#txt_username').val(),},
                  dataType:'json',
                  success: function(e) {
                    $('#username').html('Current username:'+e.current_username);
                    $('#output').html('Action:'+e.message);
                  },
                });                 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*process.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $output = array(
        'current_username'  => '',
        'message'           => '',
    );

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && trim($_POST['username']) != '') {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['prevUsername'])) {
            /*
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Users (`username`) VALUES (?)');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username'])
            $stmt->execute();
            */

            $output['message'] = 'Tracked new username: '.$_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['prevUsername'] = $_POST['username'];

        }else{
            /*
            $stmt = $db->query('UPDATE Users SET username = ? WHERE username = ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username'])
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['prevUsername'])
            */

            $output['message'] = 'Changed old username from '.$_SESSION['prevUsername']. ' to '.$_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['prevUsername'] = $_POST['username'];
        }
    }else{
        $output['message'] = 'Nothing happend';
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['prevUsername'])) $output['current_username'] = $_SESSION['prevUsername'];

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: I've tried doing something like this with my updated question, but for some reason it's not working...

Comment: Also, $_SESSION['newUsername'] is not set to anything with your code, so technically wouldn't $_SESSION['prevUsername'] be not set?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, should've been `$_POST['username'];`

Comment: This demo refreshes the page though, so session variables are changed accordingly

Comment: Changed demo to ajax based one